# "He remembered seeing a pocket compass [...] and marveling/marveled"

Tags: grammaticality, gerunds, simple-past

> Albert Einstein talked about what influenced his life as a scientist.
>   He remembered seeing a pocket compass when he was five years old and
>   (**marveling/marveled**) that the needle always pointed north.

This is from my exam question which asked to select the correct choice between *marveling* and *marveled*. The answer says *marveling* is the correct answer but it seems like *marveled* is the right answer for me. Can someone verify the answer and explain why *marveling* is correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Marveling* was probably given as the correct answer because it matches *seeing*, *seeing* and *marveling* being the things he remembered. However, a different interpretation would allow *marveled*. That would be the case if you considered that a new finite clause followed *and*, meaning that *he remembered* and *he marveled* were being treated as two separate events.

It depends on just what aspects of English the examination was testing, but in general any question, such as this one, that allows more than one possible answer is poorly designed.

Comment: Yes, but in exams you have to think about which answer the examiners want.

Answer (score 1):

He's talking about what he remembered, and the rest of the sentence after that is in continuous tense -- "he remembered **seeing** ... and **marveling** ..."

Comment: Ah that makes perfect sense. But wouldn't "marveled" be also grammatically correct?

Comment: No- you could say 'he marveled' but not 'he remembered marveled'

Comment: _Seeing_ and _marveling_ are non-finite, so they cannot be said to be in any tense at all.

Comment: I agree with Rory Alsop. I think that there's only one correct answer for this question: "_...he remembered seeing...and marveling..._".